# 3d plot in Python - max value is missing with conditional function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I'm trying to get a 3d plot where my function is conditional. However, the max value - 1 in this case is missing. If I have a function with no conditions, 1 is on the graph:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
x=np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.linspace(0,1,100)


def I_LK(x,y):
    v=1-x+y
    return np.where(v<=1, v, 1)
    #return 1-x+x*y # here there is no problem
    
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z=I_LK(X,Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(X, Y, Z, 100, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.set_zlim(0,1.1)
```

How can I get value "1" on my graph?

Comment: Thank you @JohanC, I have changed it

Answer (score 0):

In case, someone will look for it, the right method is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
x=np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.linspace(0,1,100)


def I_LK(x,y):
    v=1-x+y
    return np.where(v<=1, v, 1)
    #return 1-x+x*y # here there is no problem
    
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z=I_LK(X,Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.set_zlim(0,1.1)
```

`plot_surface` not `contour3D`